# ChoiceField disappears after overriding init method of BaseForm class

Tags: python, django

My application from an uploaded `CSV` file, reads header values and passes these headers into another class which extends `Form`. The goal was to populate this passed headers list finally into `ChoiceField`. To get the arguments, I overrode `__init__`.

Somehow on overriding the `__init__`, my choicefield disappears, without any exception appearing. The choiceField appears when I am directly using `ChoiceFields` and not overriding the `__init__` method. I tried modifying and working on different ways of overriding to get the arguments but could not succeed as in every case the `ChoiceField` goes missing. I am using `python version 3.7.1` and `Django version 1.9.8`. Any advice would be appreciated.

1.views.py:

```
def simple_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        for row in myfile:
            headerlist = row.decode('utf-8').split(",")
            break
        expense_form = ExpenseForm(headerlist)
        return visualize_view(request, expense_form)

    return render(request, 'core/simple_upload.html')


def visualize_view(request, expense_form):
    return render(request,'core/visualize_view.html',{'expense_form':expense_form})
```

2.forms.py :

```
from django import forms


class ExpenseForm(forms.Form):

 def __init__(self, headerlist, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExpenseForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    CHOICES = []
    for i in range(len(headerlist)):
        c = (i, headerlist[i])
        CHOICES.append(c)

    columns = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

3.visualize.py:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{{ expense_form.as_p }}

{% endblock %}
```

EDIT :

4.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from uploads.core import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.loginForm, name='loginForm'),
    url(r'^uploads/', views.simple_upload, name='simple_upload'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.AKASH_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field doesn't 'disappear'. It was never defined in the form in the first place.

In this code, `columns` is a local variable inside the `__init__` method. Once that method returns, the local variables are destroyed.

To dynamically create a field, you would need to assign it to the `fields` dictionary of the instance. So:

```
self.fields['columns'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
```

Note also, your code is not very Pythonic and could be greatly simplified:

```
CHOICES = [(i, header) for i, header in enumerate(headerlist)]
```

at which point you could put that directly in field definition in the class body, without needing to define `__init__` at all.

Comment: ok but if I do not use init method, how would I pass the value from view.py `expense_form = ExpenseForm(headerlist)` and get it inside the ExpenseForm class

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that `headerlist` was a parameter. You're right then, it does need to be in init, but the list comprehension is still a better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks with the list handler Daniel. Could you once also point me in how to read the selected values from the drop down

Comment: I don't understand your question. You get it from `form.cleaned_data['columns']` like any other value.\

Comment: Hey Daniel, in file `view.py` when I place `expense_form.is_valid():` after expense_form instantiation, it always returns false. Do you know the reason behind this ?

Comment: No, but if you returned the form to the template then the errors would display, telling you why it is not valid.

Comment: I changed `visualize_view()` return type to return `expense_form` and now it says `'ExpenseForm' object has no attribute 'get'`. [error Image link](https://imgur.com/a/ZWYfgsb). My concern is to get the selected value from ChoiceField but without `is_valid = True`it would not be possible.